# Three.js - why does computeVertexNormals behave differently when combined with mergeVertices?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am creating shapes with geometries and material with three.js (in a-frame) I am animating the geometry vertices by updating their position in the tick function.

In order to achieve a smooth transition of the material as the vertices update, I use `.computeVertexNormals();` in the tick function - This works as I would hope if I do not use `.mergeVertices` in the initial set up. but if I do use `.mergeVertices` then the vertexnormals are either not updated at all or they are not updated smoothly (they sometimes 'snap' to at the end of the transition).

Rather than post a lot of code here please see the following 2 fiddles for a comparison with and without `.mergeVertices`

Here is the 1st where the shape updates as I would expect (no `.mergeVertices`)

https://jsfiddle.net/e0gu8y7w/8/

And here is the 2nd where I include `.mergeVertices` (on line 37)

https://jsfiddle.net/e0gu8y7w/9/

The inclusion of `.mergeVertices` in the 2nd example is the only difference between these 2 examples.

I'm happy to copy the code here if that is more helpful but I think seeing the animation is a better way to illustrate the issue I am having. I would be grateful if you would click through and have a look.

Am I doing something wrong or is what would be expected? If so, is there a way I can achieve a smooth transition while using `.mergeVertices` as I would prefer to keep this in the code.

If any more info is needed, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: This is probably because of face winding, your first face is provided in anticlockwise (0,1,2), and the second face is in (3, 4, 5) clockwise winding. Try changing the order to (5,4,3).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response but doing that seems to lose the shading all together as you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/e0gu8y7w/10/